# Elder Scrolls Online Glitch on the ground textures on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gaming

I recently installed and started playing ESO Greymoor on Ubuntu 18 bionic. However, I have a glitch on the ground in the beginning dungeon. I'm running the game on Steam Proton 5.13. I have added screenshots relating to the issue. What might be the cause? What can I do to resolve this? Any ideas? Thanks..

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a software compatibility problem

Answer (score -1):

Had this same problem. I fixed it by changing the Wine runner in Lutris to 6.16 and DXVK to 1.8.